# How to add push notification to WebView App (both android and iOS)

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, push-notification

Hi I am developing an `webview` app using **`Java` and `Objective-C`**. My client wants me to implement push `notification` in the app. But no push `notification` service (**like firebase, OneSignal**) is added in the website. is it possible to add push `notification` in the app??

Badly need some suggestions.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: what you mean by webview app?

Comment: WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Firebase when you dont want to add it to website.

i did it so :

FCM service on andoid registers device token to my MySQl server, my Webpage generates Push notifications, with PHP and Cron by selecting tokens from SQL.

When you want to create push notifications, then you need to add something to webpage anyway. (you have to generate message and also send them to devices who have installed your app. :). )

So :

FCM, MySQl, PHP/Java/js or something what selects message and token and sends them to FCM, FCM sends it to devices.